# Question on storing a string inside a struct member in c

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers, char

Can someone explain

Why does the below code work for saving a string in a struct member

```c
struct prefix {
    char aString[70];
};

struct prefix data={
  .aString = "d08430c90b467422ae9bf7f8ecf8a77682f92764efe53e0ebe26d4ffb6fb96bf"
 };
```

while the code below does not?

```c
struct prefix {
    char aString[70];
};

struct prefix data;

data.aString = "d08430c90b467422ae9bf7f8ecf8a77682f92764efe53e0ebe26d4ffb6fb96bf"; 
              //Array type 'char [70]' is not assignable
```

Comment: the second one has nothing called data in it

Comment: @pm100  `struct prefix data;` was added if that is what you meant?

Comment: The first example uses an initializer, the second doesn't. Initializers have some special properties, such as being able to initialize an array from a string literal.

Comment: You need to `#include <string.h>` and `strcpy(data.aString, "d08430c90b467422ae9bf7f8ecf8a77682f92764efe53e0ebe26d4ffb6fb96bf")`

Comment: To clarify your problem a bit: That is not about dealing with a member of a struct. What you want to do is illegal for all arrays, not only to strings inside a struct.

Comment: @pmg`strcpy()` so basically i have to copy the string into `aString`

Comment: @Gerhardh ooh.. yeah you are right  basically what i am doing there is ,     `char aString[70];`
`aString="test";`

Comment: @Gerhardh but why is `.aString ="..."` working?

Comment: initialization: create an object and specify its value in one instruction; assignment: change the value of an object to something else. `struct prefix data = { ... };` is initialization; `struct prefix data; /* not initialized now, cannot ever initialize it later, only assign */`

Comment: @ pmg alright  you explained it perfectly  Thank you i should accept your comment as answer to this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

initialization: create an object and specify its value in one *instruction*;
assignment: change the value of a pre-existing object

```
struct prefix data = { ... }; // initialization;
struct prefix data; // not initialized now, cannot ever initialize it later, only assign
```

Answer (score 0):

the expression

```
data.aString = "d08430c90b467422ae9bf7f8ecf8a77682f92764efe53e0ebe26d4ffb6fb96bf";
```

(a string literal) is just a pointer, pointing to some initialized data segment, filled with the characters you have written between double quotes, plus a null character at the end.... it's the address of that array of characters what is passed on the assignment, and that requires a pointer type (and not an array, which is what you have declared)

Use

```
    strcpy(data.aString, "d08430c90b467422ae9bf7f8ecf8a77682f92764efe53e0ebe26d4ffb6fb96bf");
```

to copy the fixed string literal into the memory occupied by the array.  Or better, to protect you in case you use a string that doesn't fit in the array size:

```
    strncpy(data.aString, "d08430c90b467422ae9bf7f8ecf8a77682f92764efe53e0ebe26d4ffb6fb96bf", sizeof data.aString);
```